# displaying session data in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm returing session data from my database, but I'm unable to display the LastName attribute of my table, and I don't know why because the FirstName returns sucessfully. I do have the LastName attribute in my database. my view is giving me the error:Message: Undefined index: Lastname // Filename: controllers/home.php

here is my model

```
Class Membership_model extends CI_Model 
{

function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
}



function validate_student($username,$password){
   $this -> db -> select('Student_ID, Firstname,Lastname, password');

   $this -> db -> from('Student');

   $this -> db -> where('Student_ID = ' . "'" . $username . "'");
   $this -> db -> where('password = ' . "'" . MD5($password) . "'");
   $this -> db -> limit(1);

    //If it is all correct

    $query = $this -> db -> get();

    if($query->num_rows() == 1){

         return $query->result();


    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

### controller: home

```
   class Home extends CI_Controller {

     function __construct()
     {
       parent::__construct();
     }

     function index()
     {
       if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
       {
         $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
         $data['Firstname'] = $session_data['Firstname'];
         $data['Lastname'] = $session_data['Lastname'];
         $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
       }
```

---

home view:

```
<h2>Welcome <?php echo $Lastname; ?>
```

Comment: Please, learn to understand error messages. SO is not a crowd-sourced debugging tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print the session data `$session_data` , update your question with that , the error is you have no index **Lastname** in  `$session_data['Lastname'];`,

form where you set the session data `logged_in` , please update your question with that also

Comment: You're absolutely right, it works now ..sigh.. I feel so dumb.

Comment: don't worry . every body make mistakes . glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution that will surely solve the issue

on the controller add this debugging line and comment it once convinced with the internal array

```
$session = $this->session->userdata;

echo '<pre>';
   print_r($session);
echo '</pre>';
```

This is the debugging tool for you to see the sessions variable

and please be safe of the condition adding this line on the condition will do

```
 function index()
         {
$session = $this->session->userdata;
           if(array_key_exists('logged_in',$session)) //Check if array key exists in session
           {
             $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
             $data['Firstname'] = $session_data['Firstname'];
             $data['Lastname'] = $session_data['Lastname'];
             $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
           }
```